# Applying single Font to Entire web documents

Tags: html, css

I want to apply single font for each html pages through out my website.
So far I tried this:

```
* { font-family:Nyala; }
```

but this works for only one page.

Comment: You have to use this css class in every page.

Comment: Where or how is this css being added to your site?

Comment: *sidenote:* beside avoid using `*`, `font-family` is recommended to use with multiple fonts, e.g. `font-family: Nyala, Arial, sans-serif;` to provide suitable fallback for the computers that do not have the fonts installed.

Comment: This may be a very simple question, but it is on-topic. It should not be closed unless you can point to a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks! In my case i have selector(combobox) to select different type of external fonts.I want to apply selected font to entire web documents.I think a little java script code will do that.

Answer (score 5):

You should include this CSS style to each html page you wish it to take affect in.

Each HTML page should include this:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
```

And the mystyle.css is:

```
* { font-family:Nyala; }
```

**Note:** see @Raptor comments in order to improve your code.

Comment: Several *minor* problems in this answer: 1. `font-family` shouldn't use with single font; 2. `*` should be used with care, as it will lead to performance degradation; 3. if I were you, I will put CSS in a folder instead of mixing up with HTML for tidier folder structure.

Comment: @Raptor, these are not problems in this answer. They may (or may not) be regarded as problems in the code in the question, in issues other than what was asked about.

Comment: Agree, but it's good to have side notes for future visitors that tries to use these codes without learning the potential issues within.

Comment: @Raptor, then future visitors should also note that the use of `body` instead of `*`, as people have suggested, would affect the *meaning* of the rule.

Answer (score 2):

Move `* { font-family:Nyala; }` in to a external css file like style.css and call it to the head section of the all html file you want like below.

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
```

Don't forget to give exact file path where you keep your .css file.

Answer (score 0):

Add Below css

```
body{font-family:Nyala;}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make a `css` global you can place it in one common css file and make it's reference on every page.

Another point is if you are using `master page` in your website then you can place the reference of that css file once in the master page and it will automatically inherited on every content page which have master page applied.

Comment: that's a feature of web page editors, such as Dreamweaver's template feature. Does not apply to every case.

Comment: @Raptor this can be applied in .NET, PHP, Java and in every language. To me the OP isn't mentioned any technology used; so I just put the view to cover CSS globally  :).